# Rack requests files non stop

Tags: heroku, static, rack

I create a simple rack application to serve static files on heroku. But I have a problem that when trying to run the application locally with `rackup`. It seems to requests files continuously, this results hanging tab in Chrome.

What is the problem I have and how to fix it ?

config.ru

```
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/images", "/scripts", "/styles", "/components"],
  :root => "public"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

And the error :

```
...
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /scripts/scripts.js?_=1362996702033 HTTP/1.1" 200 8543 0.0007
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/jquery/jquery.min.js?_=1362996702034 HTTP/1.1" 200 92629 0.0021
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.custom.min.js?_=1362996702035 HTTP/1.1" 200 228147 0.0041
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js?_=1362996702040 HTTP/1.1" 200 11632 0.0010
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1362996702041 HTTP/1.1" 200 28545 0.0010
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.min.js?_=1362996702042 HTTP/1.1" 200 17515 0.0009
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui-ieshiv.min.js?_=1362996702043 HTTP/1.1" 200 1018 0.0006
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /scripts/scripts.js?_=1362996702044 HTTP/1.1" 200 8543 0.0007
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/jquery/jquery.min.js?_=1362996702045 HTTP/1.1" 200 92629 0.0021
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.custom.min.js?_=1362996702046 HTTP/1.1" 200 228147 0.0041
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/angular-strap/dist/angular-strap.min.js?_=1362996702051 HTTP/1.1" 200 11632 0.0007
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js?_=1362996702052 HTTP/1.1" 200 28545 0.0060
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.min.js?_=1362996702053 HTTP/1.1" 200 17515 0.0008
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui-ieshiv.min.js?_=1362996702054 HTTP/1.1" 200 1018 0.0006
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2013 11:11:43] "GET /scripts/scripts.js?_=1362996702055 HTTP/1.1" 200 8543 0.0007
...
```